# Neural Network doesn't learn beyond a specific level, loss doesn't go lower than 0.12

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a simple shallow neural network with 18 inputs(feature selected from a total of 45) and 400 samples.

Keras Implementation:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(103,input_shape=(18,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(73, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(33, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), metrics = ['accuracy', precision_m, recall_m, f1_m])

Training loss:  0.12297805808484555
Training accuracy:  0.975
Training precision:  0.9733918130397796
Training recall:  0.9833333313465118
Training f1:  0.9782239258289337

My neural network however I change its number of layers, units in each layer, weight initializers, activation functions, training epochs, learning rate doesn't budge any lower from this value.

Insights for solving this needed, please because with this classifier I get a lot of false positives

Comment: Have you used the "textbook" old school stats fits?  Have you looked at a scatterplot matrix to see if there are relationships between variables?  How did you go about picking 1/10 of your columns to retain?  What are you trying to do with your fit?  Why do you only have 400 rows?  That seems way smaller than the number of weights in your NN, which could be a problem.

Comment: 1. I haven't since I was I told to work straight on neural networks(they can model non-linear relationships.) 2. Yes there are relationships between variables. 3. I am trying to see if different feature selection methods would give different results this  1/10th is just a feature selection method I used but it comes with having to tune NN again and again. 4. Fit so I can simply predict a binary outcome. 5. 400 rows only thats the only data I can get 100 is separated out for final testing. Can you please explain the last point?

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to do some experiments with alternative network architectures, learning rates and learning rate schedules. But training loss is basically meaningless-- you should care about some measurement of generalization error. Or maybe a lower training loss isn't possible; how do you know that the model can do better?

Comment: @Sycorax exactly  Why isn't the model doing better? My technique is to first fit a model completely on my training data and then regularize, add dropouts. That way I can at least be sure that my model was trained properly. Clearly, I lack knowledge on this.

Comment: When you say "I can at least be sure that my model was trained properly" what do you mean? How does reducing the training loss below 0.12 confirm that the "model was trained properly"? What's magic about 0.12? Why does reducing the loss below 0.13 but not below 0.12 indicate that the model was not trained properly?

Comment: This is a case of research where I can not get any more data points. For me, the error going to zero would mean that the model has utilized all the data I had given it to form relationships. That way when I use validation set, the errors I'll be getting on them using error analysis will be because of some very specific examples that I can cater to outliers etc.

Comment: Irreducible noise exists in most problems. Your model isn't yet fitting to the noise; or, if it is, it's not yet fitting all of the noise. It's possible that reducing the training loss to a lower value results in a model that is overfit to your data and does not generalize. This is why reducing training loss to the absolute smallest possible value is not, on its own, a useful exercise: that model might not generalize. If generalization is important, if you want to use this model to solve a problem -- like some kind of outlier identification -- overfitting is not a good idea.

Comment: This helps. And for overfitting to not take place we'd have some training loss even in the consequence of regularization. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to assess model quality purely on the basis of training loss; this is prone to overfitting.

Irreducible noise exists in most problems. Your model isn't yet fitting to the noise; or, if it is, it's not yet fitting all of the noise. It's possible that reducing the training loss to a lower value results in a model that is overfit to your data and does not generalize. This is why reducing training loss to the absolute smallest possible value is not, on its own, a useful exercise: that model might not generalize. If generalization is important, if you want to use this model to solve a problem -- like some kind of outlier identification -- overfitting is not a good idea.